# How to convert from entity to dto using model mapper , with conversion from string to UUID

Tags: spring-boot, modelmapper

I need some help to map Entity to DTO using Model Mapper.
Here are my two pojos

```
@Data
public class ClientDTO {
    private UUID id;
    @NotNull
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private String contactEmail;
}

@Data
@Entity
public class Client {
    @Id
    private String id;
    @NotNull
    private String name;
    private String description;
    @NotNull
    private String contactEmail;
}
```

When am trying to convert between **Client** to **ClientDTO** **id** is rendered as null. I tried writing a PropertyMap and a converter but none of them is working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through the documentation and was able to find a solution to the problem. Here is the soln.

**Initialization**

```
private PropertyMap<Client, ClientDTO> clientMap;
private ModelMapper clientToClientDtoMapper;
```

Defining **PropertyMap and Converter**

```
        clientToClientDtoMapper = new ModelMapper();
        Converter<Client, UUID> uuidConverter = new AbstractConverter<Client, UUID>() {
            protected UUID convert(Client source) {
                return UUID.fromString(source.getId());
            }
        };

        clientMap = new PropertyMap<Client, ClientDTO>() {
            protected void configure() {
                try {
                    using(uuidConverter).map(source).setId(null);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.out.println("Error.");
                }
            }
        };

        clientToClientDtoMapper.addMappings(clientMap);
```

**Helper method to convert from Entity to DTO**

```
    private ClientDTO convertToDto(Client client) {

        ClientDTO clientDTO = clientToClientDtoMapper.map(client, ClientDTO.class);
        return clientDTO;
    }
```

Comment: Hey there! Bumping this as it's very similar to a question I just asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64542309/modelmapper-is-not-recognizing-uuids

Curious how you would do this if you have let's say 50 entities and want them all to have a UUID converter? Do we have to create one converter for each? Or is there a way to generalize this by only creating one converter.